# LaunchScreen.xib with a label containing CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I've got a user request to add the version number of an app to it's launchscreen.xib. Is there an easy way to populate a new UILabel in LaunchScreen.xib with CFBundleShortVersionString?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that the content displayed in `LaunchScreen.xib` is static. A simpler, albeit uglier, option would be to hard code the version into the XIB and update the XIB every time you update the app.

Comment: Yeah that's my fear as well. I'm just wondering if maybe they don't have some magic that will do it .. setting the text to $(CFBundleShortVersionString) doesn't work ;)